# Configure IIS7 to server static content through ASP.NET Runtime

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, integrated-pipeline-mode, static-files

I searched high an low and still cannot find a definite answer.

How do I configure IIS 7.0 or a Web Application in IIS so that ASP.NET Runtime will handle *all* requests -- including ones to static files like `*.js`, `*.gif`, etc?

What I'm trying to do is as follows.

We have kind of SaaSy site, which we can "brand" for every customer. "Branding" means developing a custom master page and using a bunch of `*.css` and other images.

Quite naturally, I'm using `VirtualPathProvider`, which operates like this:

```
public override System.Web.Hosting.VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
{
    if(PhysicalFileExists(virtualPath))
    {
        var virtualFile = base.GetFile(virtualPath);
        return virtualFile;
    }

    if(VirtualFileExists(virtualPath))
    {
        var brandedVirtualPath = GetBrandedVirtualPath(virtualPath);
        var absolutePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(brandedVirtualPath);

        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Serving '{0}' from '{1}'", 
            brandedVirtualPath, absolutePath), "BrandingAwareVirtualPathProvider");

        var virtualFile = new VirtualFile(brandedVirtualPath, absolutePath);
        return virtualFile;    
    }

    return null;
}
```

The basic idea is as follows: we have a `branding` folder inside our webapp, which in turn contains folders for each "brand", with "brand" being equal to host name. That is, requests to `http://foo.example.com/` should use static files from `branding/foo_example_com`, whereas `http://bar.example.com/` should use content from `branding/bar_example_com`.

Now what I want IIS to do is to forward all requests to static files to `StaticFileHandler`, which would then use this whole "infrastructure" and serve correct files. However, try as I might, I cannot configure IIS to do this.

Comment: Are you asking how to force all requests to be handled by the ASP.NET request handler, instead of IIS's default handler for those types? Or if your IIS not responding to requests for non-ASPNET files? Your question is a little unclear.

Comment: @rwmnau Thanks! Is is clearer now?

Comment: It does - thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

II7 already does that if the application pool's `Managed Pipeline Mode` is set to `Integrated` which is the default. In Integrated mode, ASP.NET handles all requests including those for static objects.

If you have to leave your application pool in `Classic Mode` then you need to use the same techniques you would use in IIS 6 to explicitly create handlers for the various static extensions.

**Additional Information Based on Comments**: I think your missing piece is creating an `HttpHandler` to handle the other extensions (.js, .css, etc.). Without this, then ASP.NET will use the default handling for these types of files. You would create a reference to you handler in your web.config. [This article](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-291916.html) is an example of creating an HttpHandler for static files.

Comment: See my edits. Does your answer still holds true in light of this?

Answer (score 1):

Kudos to everyone, but the problem was in totally different space.

`VirtualPathProvider` cannot be used in a pre-compiled web site. I'm furious.