# Deleting no more used static content locked by IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, iis, unlock, static-content

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application where a user can manage its own profile. He can change for example his own photo.

Since a photo is considered as **static content**, IIS will **lock this file**, as I understand, and **cache** it to optimise performance.

The problem happens when the user try to **change the image**. What I am doing is :

1. **Record** the new image.
2. Start **serving the new** one. The old file **will never be served**.
3. Now I need to **remove the old image**. But I having **access denied** exception.

How to tell IIS to **unlock** this old photo so that **I can delete it**.

One can imagine setting up a loop that tries to delete the photo and if cannot it will wait and retry... but I have no idea how much time that can take.

**Do you have any better solution to tell IIS to unlock file that will never be used ?**

Comment: I've never experienced this. Post the code used to both create and delete the user profile images.

Comment: Very similar problem :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381072/how-can-i-overwrite-update-a-file-that-is-currently-being-served-by-iis/9381207#9381207

Comment: Yet again, you're already serving a new file, there is a problem with your code. Please post the finite snippets that save and serve the file.

Comment: Well, by serving the new content (images), I meant the content of the data base has changed, and if a new person will ask for a dynamic page using those images, he will recieve the new content. 

My understanding of the probem is : If the old content is used (has been just served)  when we try to do the modification; the delete of the old files currently served will be denied. No? 

What I am describing above is handled by more than one class. Unfortunately I have not a single method doing that. I will try to put that in a smaller example.